# ajuda erro .htaccess

Tags: php

bom gente minha pergunta desta vez e a seguinte estou fazendo o sistema de `url amigável` em `php` já fiz o `.htaccess` que ficou assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1
```

e então eu habilitei o `rewrite` no apache e salvei todos meu arquivos de navegação em uma pasta chamada `nav` deixando somente o index fora dela no meu index logo no começo da pagina eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
$pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? $_GET['pag'] : 'default';
$pasta = 'nav';
    if(file_exists("$pasta/$pag.php")){
        include("$pasta/$pag.php");
    }else{
        header("location: error/404.html");
    }
```

porem agora quando eu tento entrar no meu `index.php` ou somente digitando o caminho da minha pasta onde esta salvo os arquivos ele não me deixa entrar sempre cai na pagina de erro alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá Leonardo, você verificou no arquivo de configuração do apache se ele suporta Override? Se ele não suporta, essas configurações tem que estar no arquivo de configuração do site (ou seja o .htaccess não vai funcionar)

Comment: sim verifiquei!

Comment: Leonardo se a pasta nav está acima do document root, tu não tem que mexer naquele file_exists ali? Teria que ser '../'.$pasta/pag.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei a lógica será a mesma, mas por não existir qualquer exemplo da parte que contém o *html* do teu exemplo, eu criei um bem simples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="home-10.html" target="_blank">Home</a> | <a href="contacto-12.html" target="_blank">Contacto</a> | <a href="ajuda-14.html" target="_blank">Ajuda</a></p>
<?php
 $p = isset($_GET['pag']) ? $_GET['pag'] : 'home';
 if(isset($p)){ 
    $pasta = 'temp'; 
    if(file_exists($pasta . '/' . $p .'.php')){
        include_once $pasta . '/' .$p . '.php';
        } else {
        header('location: error/404.html'); 
        exit();
        }
    }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podes ver, a parte que contém o *PHP* permaneceu inalterada, exceto em algumas partes, ainda assim a maior parte prevalece. O ficheiro `.htaccess` está no diretório `root` do exemplo em uso, juntamente com o `index.php`, que contém o código acima. Os *links* foram escritos por mim, e não são gerados dinamicamente à partir de um banco de dados, ou outra fonte qualquer, e coloquei neles um `target="_blank"` para facilitar na hora de testar. O meu ficheiro *home.php* é equivalente ao teu ficheiro *default*.

No mesmo diretório, criei mais duas pastas, respetivamente **error** e **temp**.

**Root**

- .htaccess
- index.php
- **error/**
- **temp/**

Na pasta **error** salvei um ficheiro com o nome *404.html* contendo a mensagem de erro exibida sempre que a página não é encontrada.

Na pasta **temp** salvei os ficheiros *home.php* e *contacto.php* contendo respectivamente o código `<?php echo "Página principal"; ?>` e `<?php echo "Página de contacto"; ?>`.

O ficheiro **.htaccess** que usei, é igualzinho o teu, exceto, mudei apenas a expressão para algo mais específico.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?pag=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+).html$ index.php?pag=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?pag=$1
```

Desta forma posso escrever os *links* de 3 formas diferentes.

- home
- home.html
- home-10.html (o tipo de *link* que usei neste exemplo).

## #Edit

> poderia me tirar uma duvida onde esta o meu código se localiza no index.php ele também e a parte principal do meu código e notei que você usou home esse seu home equivale ao meu index.php no caso eu trocaria o meu default para index ou seu home para index para adapta-lo ao meu site?

Neste caso, onde tens `if(file_exists(...)){ #instrução# }`, terias de colocar o código abaixo, no lugar de `#instrução#`. Porém, se trabalhasses com includes, podia facilitar-te em muitas coisas, e organizavas melhor o conteúdo.

```
#   
if($p === 'home'){
/*
 * Retorno ou mensagem a ser exibida na página pricipal, quando nenhuma outra está selecionada
*/
echo "Página principal"; 
} else {
include_once $pasta . '/' .$p . '.php'; 
}
#
```

## #Edit 2

Substitui todo o código php no teu `index.php` e coloca isto no lugar do código antigo:

```
$p = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'default';
 if(isset($p)){ 
    $pasta = 'temp'; 
    if(file_exists($pasta . '/' . $p .'.php')){
        #   
        if($p === 'default'){
            /*
             * Retorno ou mensagem a ser exibida na página pricipal, quando nenhuma outra está selecionada
             */
            echo "Página principal"; 
        } else {
            include_once $pasta . '/' .$p . '.php'; 
        }
        #
        } else {
        if($p === 'default'){
            echo "Página principal";    
        } else {
            header('location: error/404.html'); 
            exit(); 
        }
        }
    }
```

Embora isso resolva o teu problema atual, não recomendo essa prática. Existem muitas e muitas formas de fazer isso com resultados agradáveis. Recomendo que te informes mais acerca das *URLs amigáveis*.

Comment: poderia me tirar uma duvida onde esta o meu código se localiza no `index.php` ele também e a parte principal do meu código e notei que você usou home esse seu home equivale ao meu `index.php` no caso eu trocaria o meu default para index ou seu home para index para adapta-lo ao meu site?

Comment: Olha editei a minha resposta, leia a parte _#Edit_, e veja se isto resolve esse problema.

Comment: cara eu acho que você nao intendeu o que eu Quiz perguntar vou perguntar de uma forma mais fácil este home que você esta chamando no `isset` ele e um arquivo `home.php` ou e uma pasta chamada `home`?

Comment: É um arquivo `home.php`.

Comment: ele entao onde voce colocou home no `isset` eu coloco `index` e isso neh?

Comment: alterei o meu para `index` mas infelizmente nao mudou nada ele continua retornando para a pagina de erro nao abrindo o `index.php`

Comment: Qual valor estás tu a usar aqui: `$p = isset($_GET['pag']) ? $_GET['pag'] : 'home';` ? Home ou Default ?

Comment: antes estava default e nao pegava agora troquei para index e nao pega tambem

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta, faça o teste e diga o que retornou agora.

Comment: agora nao deu erro ele retornou pagina principal

Comment: Está tudo em ordem ?

Comment: aparenta mas e esses echo pagina principal posso tira-los?

Comment: Onde está `echo "Pagina principal"`, é onde estaria o conteúdo da página principal, podes remover eles e colocar o conteúdo que queres que seja exibido na página principal. Mas dessa forma terás um código demasiado extenso, e meio confuso.

Comment: intendi vou ver o que eu posso fazer para reduzir esse codigo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma também:

```
$pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? $_GET['pag'] : 'default';
$pasta = "nav";
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/{$pasta}/{$pag}.php")){
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/{$pasta}/{$pag}.php");
    } else{
        header("location: error/404.html");
    }



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: ele sempre esta entrando direto ja na pasta do error amigo tanto o meu codigo quanto o seu voce digita o caminho do site ele ja cai na pagina de error

Comment: editei minha resposta tente p ver

Comment: continua caindo na pagina de error

Comment: ai se eu tento colocar no else o o href do index ele me aparece que esta dando loop de redirecionamento

Comment: sua lógica que está incorreta ali no PHP

Comment: aonde esta incorreto poderia me apontar?