# Como usar URLs Amigáveis para criar link de download

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte banco de dados:

```
ID | Chave | Nome | Tamanho
===========================
1  | q3T49 | Arq1 | 20 MB
2  | 56Q4u | Arq2 | 35 MB
3  | 7fa4b | Arq3 | 89 MB
4  | 13dqa | Arq4 | 49 MB
```

E os arquivos estão guardados em `./arquivos`, porem cada um com sua chave, por exemplo, o arquivo de nome `Arq3` está em `./arquivos/7fa4b/Arq3`.

Eu gostaria de fazer uma URL amigável em que ao entrar no link `site.com/download/chave` faria o download diretamente, por exemplo, quando entrar no link `site.com/download/56Q4u` automaticamente ele faria download do `Arq2`.

Por enquanto meu `.htaccess` está apenas o básico para tirar o .php do final.

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo bem simples, para teres uma mínima noção do que deves realmente fazer, é o seguinte:

```
<?php
// index.php

// apresentar os respectivos links
print "<a href=\"download/{$item['chave']}\" target=\"_blank\">{$item['nome']}</a>";
print "<a href=\"download/{$item['chave']}\" target=\"_blank\">{$item['nome']}</a>";

// verificar se o link foi clicado
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : null; // a=download
$f = isset($_GET['f']) ? $_GET['f'] : null; // f=chave_no_banco

if(isset($a) && isset($f)){ 
    /* algo melhor elaborado aqui, 
    para verificar os detalhes da chave e retornar 
    dados correspondentes do banco antes de iniciar a transferencia,
    ou algo semelhante
    */
    print "A transferir: <br/>";
    print "<strong>ficheiro: </strong>{$f}<br>";
    sleep(1);
    include_once 'download.php';
}
```

Para o **htaccess** poderias adicionar isto:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=download&f=$1
```

Para o download do ficheiro em questão:

```
<?php
$name= $_GET['f'];
$randNumber = date('d-m-Y');

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($randNumber.$name) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("_directorio_do_arquivo_no_servidor/".$name);
    exit;
?>
```

**NOTA:** Apesar de sem algo funcional, não digo para já que é recomendável, existem procedimentos que deves ainda implementar e várias modificações a fazer, para que seja implementado com sucesso. Consulta também a documentação do *apache*.

## Referências

- [ajuda erro .htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90550/ajuda-erro-htaccess)
- [How to download file from database/folder using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367104/how-to-download-file-from-database-folder-using-php)